# An update to MsalAuthenticationTemplate ran an effect , error when writing unit test with jest in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock, msal-react

I am writing unit tests with jest, my unit tests are running but I am always getting below error.
Due to this error, it does not show coverage and test description which ran successfully

```
console.error
      Warning: An update to MsalAuthenticationTemplate ran an effect, but was not wrapped in act(...).
      
      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
      
      act(() => {
    /* fire events that update state */
  });
  /* assert on the output */
  
  This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
      at MsalProvider (C:\XXXXXX\node_modules\@azure\msal-react\src\MsalProvider.tsx:25:31)
      at ThemeProvider (C:\XXXXXX\node_modules\@material-ui\core\node_modules\@material-ui\styles\ThemeProvider\ThemeProvider.js:48:24)
      at Provider (C:\XXXXXX\node_modules\react-redux\lib\components\Provider.js:21:20)
```

anyone faced same issue and has the sample mocking of the MsalAuthenticationTemplate ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you managed to fix this error? Please share the solution. It would be really helpful :)

Comment: hey, no i was not able to find solution for it. if you find it please put in the answer so that it can help community